# Map not showing when using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API to get a single map to show. I'm using Javascript.

It should be a single page with one header and one map below the header. I signed up for the Google Maps API recently, so I'm not sure if it takes a certain amount of time for the API key to be active or not. I've got other CSS files and a googlemaps.js file that doesn't have anything in it yet.

Here's my code. Any ideas why it's not working?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0;'>
    <title>API(s)</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/semantic.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/main.css'>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="ui two column centered stackable grid container">
        <div class="column">
            <h1 class="goog-header">Location Based Image Search</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui one column stackable grid container js-images-container">
        <div class="column">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXTmorapOu1WquB3VlsLrckhE45Bgfrfw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<script src='javascript/googlemaps.js'></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add width and height on the map div element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your map DIV to:

```
<div id="map" style="width:800px;height:600px"></div>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I guess there is no "default" setting for that. Thanks again.